# sheet_name=None is causing an attribute error

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have an excel sheet with multiple sheets.  I am trying to merge them into 1 Dataframe, then export to excel sheet with only 1 sheet.  I can get the information into one dataframe, but when I try to export I get the error:

AttributeError:  'collections.OrderedDit' object has no attribute 'to_excel'

The script is super simple:

`import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("E 59th Street.xlsx", sheet_name=None)
df.to_excel("Grant_Test.xlsx")`

Here is the error:

```
df.to_excel("Grant_Test.xlsx")  AttributeError: 'collections.OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'to_excel'
```

I cannot find any reason adding sheet_name=None would cause this error.

What is going on with my script?

Comment: Because a dict of DataFrames is returned, not one DataFrame.

Comment: From the docs, setting the `sheet_name=None` parameter: "None: All sheets", so it will ready each sheet as an element in an ordered_dict. To get one DF out, you need to index into the dict, then call `to_excel` on only the one DF

Answer (score 1):

Thats makes `df` into `OrderedDict` of the sheets

try to do this:

```py
df.values()[0].to_excel("Grant_Test.xlsx")
```

## Explanation

`df` is all your sheets, when you do `read_excel` you get an `OrderedDict` object of all your sheets

`df.values()` makes you get all your `DataFrame` object (Your sheets)

`df.values()[0]` you have only got one sheet, so we get the first one